# Is there a Perl module that works similarly to the Unix "which" command?

Tags: perl, unix

I was on Perlmonks and found this great listing:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=627015

But it was missing "which", the function that searches for an executable in all the directories in your PATH. (I am porting a Perl script to Windows.)

Is there a Perl module that simulates this?

Comment: There's also a `which` in [PerlPowerTools](http://perlpowertools.com), and I have my own tool I call [rhich](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::rhich) that's does a similar job but with regexes to match programs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`File::Which`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Which).  Always check CPAN!  :)

Comment: Thanks. Google failed me because "which" is a common word and all I got was garbage from my searches.

Comment: Well, why use Google when you can use CPAN Search (http://search.cpan.org). It's very hard to easily find things at www.cpan.org.

Comment: The File::Which::which doc says that it is a "Perl implementation of the which utility as an API". However, with version 1.09, calling File::Which::which("/bin/ls") returns undef. Calling "which /bin/ls" from a *nix shell returns "/bin/ls".

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this Snippet?

[`which` (for Windows) in pure perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=545096)

The follow-up points to the module [File::Which](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Which) on CPAN.

Comment: There is also the thread [How to find out if an executable is in my path](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=305851) about an implementation of `which` using pure Perl. Cheers :-)